# Is the size of the sum of squared errors in OLS regression invariant to linear transformation?

Tags: regression

Suppose I am doing OLS regression. I have a data set $\lbrace \mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y}\rbrace$.

$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = \text{argmin}_{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\lbrace (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}) \rbrace $$

I am at a minimum since my Hessian is $2\mathbf{XX^T}$, which is positive definite. My minimum is

$$(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}})$$

Then I perform a linear transformation on my data such that $T_1: \mathbf{X}\rightarrow T_1( \mathbf{X})$.

Does there always exist a transformation $T_2: \boldsymbol{\beta} \rightarrow T_2(\boldsymbol{\beta})$ that essentially acts as an inverse such that I return to the same value? i.e. where

$$(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}) = (\mathbf{y}-T_1(\mathbf{X})T_2(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}))^T(\mathbf{y}-T_1(\mathbf{X})T_2(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}))$$

I was able to show this for a simple case but I was wondering if this is true generally and if so why.

For instance, let $c,d \in \Bbb{R}$

$$X_{ij} \rightarrow c (X_{ij}+ d) $$

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a "linear transformation" of the design matrix $X.$  I suspect you intend that to be a linear transformation of the *column space* of $X,$ not of $X$ itself, but it's not completely clear that's what you're after.  Moreover, that transformation of the column space had better be invertible for otherwise there are counterexamples.

Comment: @whuber I added an example transformation.

Comment: Thank you, but the issue remains: what exactly is *the most general* transformation you have in mind?